# what should i change so my file will show up?

Tags: c++, file, txt

I starting over a c++ journey and I cannot upload a file and parse it. Could you please tell me what is wrong with my code?

thank you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    
    std::string FileName("upload.txt");
    std::ifstream MyFile(FileName);
    MyFile.open(FileName);
    std::string LastName;
    std::string Name;
    int Number;
  
    
    if (!MyFile.is_open()){
        std::cout <<"The fils is not opened \n"<< std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<"olivier"<< std::endl;
    while (MyFile >> LastName >> Name >> Number){
        std::cout<<"olivier"<< std::endl;
        std::cout<< LastName << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's impossible to say without more details. What *happens?* Do you get build errors? Does it not run as expected? Do you get crashes? Something else? Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: _I cannot upload a file and parse it._ What happens? My wild guess: You're trying to run this from an IDE. The file is not opened. The usual trap is that you assume the current working directory of your application is the folder of your source code. In IDEs, this is usually not the case. (Instead, it is the folder where the binary is stored into - usually.) You have to setup the current working directory for your application to fix this.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the program only executes the line std::cout<<"olivier"<< std::endl;

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Thank you for your answer. I am using Xcode 13.4.1 and I tried to change the directory indexing the project folder but it still does not work. The only line executed is the std::cout<<"olivier"<< std::endl (which is a line to test the code). I assume that if the file is not opened it should execute the line std::cout <<"The fils is not opened \n"<< std::endl unless I am wrong.

Comment: Assuming you mean the *first* of those lines (don't have debugging-output that are exactly the same, it makes it harder to distinguish it), then the file opens successfully, but it fails to read. Which can only mean that the file you attempt to read is empty. You're probably not opening the file you're expecting to open.Have you tried going into the project settings, to find the settings where running the program is configured, and then setting the [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) to where the "real" file is located?

Comment: There is no 'upload' here. Do you mean 'open'? Don't misuse standard terminology.

Comment: Please, have a look at [Setting the Current Working Directory for Xcode Command-Line Projects](https://www.meandmark.com/blog/2013/12/setting-the-current-working-directory-for-xcode-command-line-projects/). (I must admit that I never used XCode myself.)

Answer (score 1):

You are opening the file twice

```
std::ifstream MyFile(FileName);
MyFile.open(FileName);
```

First time you use constructor and then you are trying to open the same file. Just remove the `MyFile.open(FileName);` and everything will be fine.

Comment: I struggled a bit to believe it and made an MCVE: [Test on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/604be438f354cda1). (I cannot remember that I ever made this mistake myself and thus haven't any experience about this.) To my surprise, I noticed that the file stream is still reported as open but not good anymore. In fact, nothing can be read from that stream afterwards...

Comment: Out of curiosity, I extended the first MCVE a bit: [2nd Test on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e01b02d6b1fd8cc2). The call of `fstream::open()` seems to set the error flag. Clearing it the stream becomes good again but it's still the original file which has been opened.